# How to JOIN two indices in Sphinx, (No index merging)?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Lets suppose, I have two indices, created from respective MySQL table.

```
folder: folder_id, resume_id, status 
resume: resume_id, title, skills, experience etc...
```

I want few data that needs JOIN on the basis of `resume_id`. We can have auto increment field in Indices, if required.
 
According to me, Options available with me are:
1. **Index merging**: I don't want to merge index, because it will take much space. I have data in billions.
2. **Creation of one Index after joining tables**. Problem with this solution is that, a folder have many resumes, and one resume can be in many other folders (Many to many). So, same resume's data will be indexed many times, thereby provoking data redundancy.

Please suggest a way, if possible in sphinx, to achieve this, maintaining the performance, and reducing data redundancy as well. I have to use this in production environment with billions of data. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a virtual join in your scripting code (for example, PHP). The performance won't be affected and you won't have to merge indexes.

An alternative way would be to create an index based on an additional condition (you're saying that you want "few" data, which means that there must be an additional condition).